# Logging in python with JSON configuration - things get logged more than once?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, logging

I am using Python 3, and I am learning how to use logging. I am looking at the code from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html and https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/.

I tried to modify part of the first two code blocks in the first link, the main module and the auxiliary module, to use a JSON file. But when I ran the main file, I get certain log outputs repeated 3 times, but I don't know why, or what to change so that lines aren't repeated but are still outputted to the same .log file.

.log file:
[.log file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSiMC.jpg)

My JSON file:

```
{
"version": 1,
"disable_existing_loggers": false,
"formatters": {
    "simple": {
        "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    }
},

"handlers": {
    "debug_file_handler": {
        "class": "logging.FileHandler",
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "formatter": "simple",
        "filename": "debug.log",
        "encoding": "utf8"
    }
},

"loggers": {
    "spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
    },
    "spam_application.auxiliary": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
    }

},

"root": {
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
}}
```

and for the main file:

```
import auxiliary_module
import os
import json
import logging.config

with open('python_logging_configuration.json', 'r') as logging_configuration_file:
config_dict = json.load(logging_configuration_file)

logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('creating an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
a = auxiliary_module.Auxiliary()
logger.info('created an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
logger.info('calling auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')
a.do_something()
logger.info('finished auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')
logger.info('calling auxiliary_module.some_function()')
auxiliary_module.some_function()
logger.info('done with auxiliary_module.some_function()')
```

And for the auxiliary_module file

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application.auxiliary')

class Auxiliary:
def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary')
    self.logger.info('creating an instance of Auxiliary')
    self.logger.debug('debug in Auxiliary')

def do_something(self):
    self.logger.info('doing something')
    a = 1 + 1
    self.logger.info('done doing something')

def some_function():
    module_logger.info('received a call to "some_function"')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer

This is because of a [special property called `propagate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate). It is a flag that determines whether a logger should pass a log record to its parent logger (`propagate=True`) or not (`propagate=False`). You need either to remove the common configuration from the intermediate loggers, leaving only the unique stuff, or pass `"propagate": false` to all the loggers.

### Long answer

#### loggers hierarchy and log record propagation

All loggers in Python are organized in a hierarchy: there is always a root logger, returned when you call `getLogger` without a name:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
```

All the loggers you create with a name are children of the root logger, so

```
my_logger = logging.getLogger('my-special-logger')
```

has `root_logger` as parent. Now, when you call `my_logger.info('Hello world')`, the following happens: `my_logger` will

- handle the record itself
- check whether it has `propagate` set to `True`, if yes, then it will pass the record to its parent logger (the root logger in this case), which will also handle the record.

This is also visualized in the [logging flow diagram](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow), you can check it out if you want.

Now, you can probably already guess what happens if I configure both loggers like this:

```json
"loggers": {
    "my-special-logger": {
        "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
    },
},

"root": {
    "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
}
```

On each incoming log record, the `my-special-logger` writes the record to `debug.log`, then passes the record further up to `root`, which also writes the record to `debug.log`. So the record will appear twice in the end.

#### module namespace hierarchy

However, the question is: why there are three copies of some records in the debug log? The answer is found in [Advanced Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial):

> Each [logger] instance has a name, and they are conceptually arranged in a namespace hierarchy using dots (periods) as separators. For example, a logger named `scan` is the parent of loggers `scan.text`, `scan.html` and `scan.pdf`.

So now you can evaluate the logger hierarchy in your code:

```
root                                                -> writes to debug.log
└── spam_application
     └── spam_application.auxiliary                -> writes to debug.log
          └── spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary -> writes to debug.log
```

#### solution

The propagation of records in the logging hierharchy has the advantage that you don't need to repeat the configuration for each logger. So, when your application should log to `debug.log`, add the `debug_file_handler` to root logger once and it will already serve all the other loggers, no matter whether you add them to config or not.

This way, your initial config can be reduced to:

```json
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": { ... },

    "handlers": {
        "debug_file_handler": { ... }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"]
    }
}
```

The alternative to that would be passing `"propagate": false` to each explicitly configured logger so the messages won't be handled multiple times by the `debug_file_handler`:

```json
{
    "version": 1,

    ...

    "loggers": {
        "spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"],
            "propagate": false
        },
        "spam_application.auxiliary": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["debug_file_handler"],
            "propagate": false
        }
    },

    ...
```